# VUEJS pdf-viewer-vue cannot take path file as source

Tags: vue.js, pdf-viewer

I'm building VueJS component pdf-viewer with [pdf-viewer-vue](https://hhttps://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-viewer-vue), and in the desc says that we can use props **source** as source of document,it only takes document URL and Base64, but I have only path to the pdf file in a public folder, and it won't work with path folder. How do I approach this ?

```
          <PDFViewer
              source="../../puclic/file.pdf"
              style="max-height: 780px; max-width: 1108px"
              @download="handleDownload"

          />
```

Comment: I think that is because you have typed `puclic` instead of `public` in source prop.

Comment: I also tried to store it in assets folder, it doesn't work

Comment: without proper information about your file structure it will be hard to tell you why its not working